# Using freestyle and normal textures in one scene

Tags: rendering, freestyle

How to combine Freestyle with normal textures?
I have a townscape scene In bender 2.79. All objects have a simple freestyle outline. I want to have the bottom most object (a landscape) to be a normal texture, (not freestyle) so can add an image to it, does any one know how I can do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set freestyle visibility per-collection. Add your landscape in another collection and set it to EXCLUSIVE in the bottom of the line set properties :

[image]